# Android Development: Changing Background Tinton Button with Java

Tags: java, android, button

So I am working on an app using android studio, and in the XML file, I realized if you edit the android:BackgroundTint of a button, you can change the color or the button, however, I wanted to change this within my java code, and I cannot figure out how to do this. The reason I dont just simply change android:BackgroundColor is that that changes the overall shape and effect of the button, and I do not want to sacrifice this. Any help to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry typo in title, should be Tint on instead of tinton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. This is the code I was looking for:

> button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);